# Linux access to the port 'ttyUSB0' is denied via .Net5 even as root

Tags: c#, linux, serial-port, debian

1. On Debian, trying to access ttyUSB0 (Serial over USB using an FTDI cable).
2. My user groups: myuser tty dialout cdrom floppy sudo audio dip video plugdev netdev bluetooth lpadmin scanner

the .Net5 code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("whoami");
var serialPort = new SerialPort("ttyUSB0", 115200);
serialPort.Open();
```

the Serial port nugget: `<PackageReference Include="System.IO.Ports" Version="5.0.1"/>`

With Putty as either my user or root, I can access ttyUSB0.

Running `dotnet progname.dll` (as my user) and `sudo dotnet progname.dll` both give me the same result UnauthorizedAccessException:

```
**af**
Unhandled exception. System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the port 'ttyUSB0' is denied.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unknown error 203
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.IO.Ports.SafeSerialDeviceHandle.Open(String portName)
   at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream..ctor(String portName, Int32 baudRate, Parity parity, Int32 dataBits, StopBits stopBits, Int32 readTimeout, Int32 writeTimeout, Handshake handshake, Boolean dtrEnable, Boolean rtsEnable, Boolean discardNull, Byte parityReplace)
   at System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.Open()


**root**
Unhandled exception. System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the port 'ttyUSB0' is denied.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: No such file or directory
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.IO.Ports.SafeSerialDeviceHandle.Open(String portName)
   at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream..ctor(String portName, Int32 baudRate, Parity parity, Int32 dataBits, StopBits stopBits, Int32 readTimeout, Int32 writeTimeout, Handshake handshake, Boolean dtrEnable, Boolean rtsEnable, Boolean discardNull, Byte parityReplace)
   at System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.Open()
```

Comment: Is it necessary to add `/dev/` to the beginning of the device file path to make it `/dev/ttyUSB0`? Then you will need to check the owner and permissions of the device file.

Comment: Thank you! This was it. Can you set this as the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posted as an answer because it was resolved with the commented content:

Is it necessary to add `/dev/` to the beginning of the device file path to make it `/dev/ttyUSB0`?

Then you will need to check the owner and permissions of the device file.